# Using fadeto and animate with backgrounds?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to fade my background in and out on the document load but it doesn't seem to be working. Im using RGBA and just setting the opacity to 0.75 and then to 0. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Here is my code;

```
jQuery( "#topbar" ).mouseenter(function(e) { // h2 faded up image is done using css

        jQuery("#topbar").css( "background", "rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.75)");

        });



  jQuery( "#topbar" ).mouseleave(function(e) {
             jQuery("#topbar").css( "background", "none");
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**fadeTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

```
jQuery("#topbar").fadeTo("slow", 0.75);
```

The first parameter is the speed of the animation. It can be "slow", "fast" or you can input value in milliseconds.

And second parameter is the opacity.

Here is the full code.

```
jQuery( "#topbar" ).mouseenter(function(e) { 

    jQuery("#topbar").fadeTo(2000,0.75);

}).mouseleave(function(e) {

    jQuery("#topbar").fadeTo(2000,1);

});
```

---

Using **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

```
jQuery('#topbar').animate({'opacity':0.75},2000);
```

Comment: Yeah but this will change the opacity of everything within topbar and not just the background.